# the difference between 'stretched off' and 'stretched out'

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions

Could you explain what is the difference between 'stretched off' and 'stretched out'?

stretched off

> Outside the train endless fields stretched off, broken by an
>   occasional farm building.
>
> Outside the train the brown fields stretched
>   off endlessly.

stretched out

> Above the fields a long mass of translucent smoke lay stretched out.
>
> A double row of stores stretched out ahead of him.

The Commuter
by Philip K. Dick

Comment: It seems that "stretch off" implies something vast which goes far in all directions, but "stretch out" implies something narrower and sort of one-directional!

Comment: stretch off [**into the distance**]

Answer (score 1):

*Stretch out* is a common phrasal verb; originally it was a sort of intensified version of *stretch*, emphasising how far the stretching went; but I would say that today it is probably more common than plain *stretch*, except in the special meaning of "stretch a muscle as part of physical exercise or warm-up". So *stretched out* is more or less interchangeable with *stretched*.

*Stretch off* is not a phrasal verb, as far as I know. So *off* has its normal meaning, and *stretched off* means something like "stretched [out] into the distance".

Comment: Could you give the appropriate link in the dictionary for “off” for this example.

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/off?s=t , adverb, meaning 3